# An inequality about the circumference of a simple 2-connected graph

Tags: inequality, graph-theory

Suppose $G$ is a simple graph, which, by definition is an undirected graph without multiple edges and loops. Set $v,e$ to be the number of vertices and edges. Assume $G$ is connected, and still connected when any vertex is deleted. Prove that the circumference(length of the longest cycle) $l$ of $G$ is at least $\frac{2e}{e-v+2}$.

It is easy to reformulate the inequality $l\ge\frac{2e}{e-v+2}$ as
$$e\ge\frac{l}{l-2}(v-2). $$
This inequality now looks like the famous result that any planar graph with girth(length of the shortest cycle) $g$ satisfies $e\le \frac{g}{g-2}(v-2)$ which comes from Euler's formula directly. By looking at that result carefully, we can find some graphs where the equality holds. For example, let $G$ be a graph with vertex $v_1,\cdots,v_n,w_1,w_2$, set up edges between $v_i$ and $w_j$, then $v=n+2,e=2n,l=g=4$. This graph is planar and all the faces are quadrilateral, so $l=g$ makes things tight.

But I have no idea how to deal with our inequality. In this case we can't use Euler's formula because the graph does not have to be planar. And our inequality is reversed compared to the planar one. Although when $e$ becomes larger, the bound for $l$ gets more loose. It is still confusing how one could cut down the number of edges.

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't a 1-connected graph just a connected graph? Your description: ...is connected, and still connected when any vertex is deleted... seems to be saying that the graph is 2-connected